# How can i create one recyclerview into another recyclerview android

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview

Here is my json response , How can i create layout with one recyclerview into another recyclerview in android

```
{
"status": "success",
"message": "Scholarships fetched successfully",
"data": [
    {
        "scholarship_id": "1",
        "scholarship_name": "Test1",
        "scholarship_overview": "<p>Test1</p>\n",
        "university_details": [
            {
                "university_name": "Test2",
                "country_name": "USA",
                "courses": "B.Sc / M.Sc"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "scholarship_id": "2",
        "scholarship_name": "Test2",
        "scholarship_overview": "<p>Test2</p>\n",
        "university_details": [
            {
                "university_name": "Test2",
                "country_name": "USA",
                "courses": "B.Sc / M.Sc"
            },
            {
                "university_name": "Test3",
                "country_name": "Switzerland",
                "courses": "B.E. / B.Tech"
            }
        ]
    },
```

How can i create Layout and bind with it into recyclerview, i want data object put into recylerview and in data recyclerview add another recyclerview into data Recyclerview in android.

Comment: how can i do . i dont understand @Zlytherin

Answer (score 0):

Just add recycler view for item in view holder.

In first recycler view you will implement adapter and view holder, in view holder add layout that contain another recyclerview, then handle the nested recycler view in first recycler view adapter.

Comment: you have any example ? @Khaled

Comment: check this Nested RecyclerView or Inner Recycler View in android
http://mithunkumarc.blogspot.com/2016/09/nested-recyclerview-or-inner-recycler.html

and this 
https://www.codexpedia.com/android/android-nested-recyclerviews-with-expandable-list/